# 'endofline' option stays false after write operation

Tags: save, line-breaks

When one opens a file with an incomplete last line (File does not end with `0x0A` / a new line character), the `endofline` option is set to false (`:echo &endofline` will print `0`) and the `[NOEOL]` indicator is displayed.

If one saves such a file (`:w`), the new line character will be added, the `[NOEOL]` indicator will disappear and the filesize will grow by one byte. However, `:echo &endofline` will still print `0`. I would expect the `endofline` option being in sync with the `[NOEOL]` indicator.

Is there a way to keep the `[NOEOL]` indicator in sync with the `endofline` option? Or alternatively to query the status of the `[NOEOL]` indicator?

Thanks to [@filbranden's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25401/26235) I added the following line to my `.vimrc` file:

```
au BufWritePost * if !&endofline && &fixeol && !&binary | set endofline |  endif
```

The `endofline` option will now be updated if a new line character was *added* to a file's end. However, this is only half the way: If I *remove* a trailing new line character from a file, the `endofline` option will stay `true`.

FYI: I need this to edit some binary files (`:set binary | %!xxd` / `%!xxd -r`) without corruption through accidental added/removed trailing new line characters.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Your follow up is more like a separate question, since it's really about the behavior of the binary/eol in the `:%!` operation... @D.BenKnoble you wrote [vim-hex](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-hex/) (which you @dirdi might want to try!), can you pitch in on adding/removing newlines when xxd'ing back and forth?

Comment: @filbranden you are right: it boils down to the ```:%!``` operation. Vim adds a trailing new line char to the stream if the ```endofline``` option is set. But the ```endofline``` option is not in sync with the buffer's content. AFAICS ```vim-hex``` is also affected by this problem.

Comment: Just saw this; I’ll have to do some digging (I havent had to touch vim-hex’s code for a while). If there is a bug about adding trailing newlines, I’d love to know and fix it.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is intentional, to keep track of the original `[noeol]` status of the file when it was first read.

Note that you can control whether to keep the original `[noeol]` status of a file when writing it by setting [`'nofixeol'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27fixeol%27):

> When writing a file and this option is on, `<EOL>` at the end of file will be restored if missing. Turn this option off if you want to preserve the situation from the original file. See the `'endofline'` option.

(You can also achieve the same effect of preserving the `[noeol]` status by setting the `'binary'` option, which you can do with the `-b` command-line option or using `:e ++bin`.)

Vim will only `set noeol` when *reading* files that don't include a final `<EOL>`. See [`:help 'eol'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27eol%27):

> [...] This option is automatically set or reset **when starting to edit a new file**, depending on whether file has an `<EOL>` for the last line in the file. Normally you don't have to set or reset this option. [...] it is used **to remember** the presence of a `<EOL>` for the last line in the file, so that when you write the file the situation from the original file can be kept. But you can change it if you want to.

So I understand the rationale here is that it will keep remembering the *original* state of this setting, if later on you decide you *want* to preserve it, with `set nofixeol`, the fact that you may have written the file doesn't really affect the original `[noeol]` status of the file, which is still remembered.

And since `'fixeol'` is the default, the fact that the original `[noeol]` status is remembered doesn't really matter much, since unless you changed this setting, Vim will end up fixing the file when writing it.

If you *really* want to reset the `[noeol]` status of the file after writing it, one way to do it is by reading it back using a bare `:e`, which will simply re-read the file being edited. As documented, this will reset the `[noeol]` status of the file, which should now be fixed.

(Another alternative is for you to check whether Vim will have fixed it, by checking that `'binary'` is disabled and `'fixeol'` is enabled, and then update `'eol'` accordingly. This reimplements some internal Vim logic, but this logic should be fairly stable, so it's not that an unreasonable thing to do.)

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I was able to solve half of my problem ;D I updated my question and maybe you can extend/update your answer accordingly.